# find even numbers in given array

Tags: php, arrays

For example the given array is

```
$data = array(1, ‘alpha’, 4, array(‘gamma’, 6, 8, array(7,9,11,90), 22, 60), 14, 51, ‘beta’);
```

the expected result is

```
array(4, array(6, 8, array(90), 22, 60), 14)
```

I tried this code

```
function getEvenValues($array, $holder = array()) {
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if (gettype($value) == 'array') {
            getEvenValues($value);
        }
          else if(gettype($value) == 'integer'){
            if($value % 2 == 0){
              array_push($holder, $value);      
            }
        }
    }
    return $holder;
}

print_r(getEvenValues($data));
```

But didn't get expected result

Comment: What were the results. Just to save us having to copy/paste that code and run it for ourselves

Comment: Actually you need to look up recursion. Look at a few examples and see what yuo are doing wrong.

Comment: what's expected result?

Comment: the expected result is  array(4, array(6, 8, array(90), 22, 60), 14)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check bellow code:

```
function getEvenValues($array, $holder = array()) {
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            array_push($holder,getEvenValues($value));
        }
         else if(gettype($value) == 'integer'){
             if($value % 2 == 0){
                 array_push($holder, $value);      
             }
        }
    }
    return $holder;
}
```

I will provide you the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

```
function findEvens ($arr) {
    $res = [];
    foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
        if (gettype($v) == 'integer') {
            if ($v % 2 == 0) $res[] = $v;
        } else if (is_array($v)) {
            $res[] = findEvens($v);
        }
    }
    return $res;
}
```